# KeyError while executing SQL with parameters

Tags: python, teradata

I am getting `KeyError` while running below code. I am trying to pass parameters using separate `parameters` variable.

Code:

```
import teradata

host,username,password = 'hostname','uname', 'pwd'
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="APtest", version="1.0", logConsole=False)
connect = udaExec.connect(method="odbc",system=host, username=username, password=password, dsn="dsnname")

val1='NULL'
val2='NULL'
parameters={'param1':val1, 'param2': val2}

qry="""
    SELECT number
    FROM table
    WHERE number = %(param1)s
    AND col=%(param2)s
    """

connect.execute(qry, parameters)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/teradata/udaexec.py", line 675, in execute
    self.internalCursor.execute(query, params, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/teradata/udaexec.py", line 745, in execute
    self._execute(self.cursor.execute, query, params, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/teradata/udaexec.py", line 787, in _execute
    logParamCharLimit)
  File "/tmp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/teradata/udaexec.py", line 875, in _getParamsString
    if isinstance(params[0], (list, tuple)):
KeyError: 0
```

If i write the query in below manner then it works but i have very long list of parameters therefore need it in separate parameter variable.

This works:

```
qry="""
    SELECT number
    FROM table
    WHERE number = '%s'
    AND col='%s'
    """ % (val1, val2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, teradata does not support dictionaries for parameters. Use a list instead.

```
parameters = [val1, val2]

qry="""
    SELECT number
    FROM table
    WHERE number = %s
    AND col=%s
    """

connect.execute(qry, parameters)
```

Comment: I was trying to use dictionaries so that i can have one set of all parameters and then i dont have to define separate parameter list for all sqls. But as i understand it does not support Dict. its same as passing `% (val1, val2)` at the end of sql. But i tried above, i am getting error `"parameters ({}).".format(len(p), numParams))
teradata.api.InterfaceError: ('PARAMS_MISMATCH', 'The number of supplied parameters (2) does not match the expected number of parameters (0).')`